# How can i enter current date and time in textbox

Tags: java, selenium

I want to enter the current date and time along with second  in a text box ; How can I do that ?

The code what I have written is as below , but it is only entering the string value what I am passing in send keys , which is clearly indicating I am not in correct track .

Any suggestion ?

```
// Create object of SimpleDateFormat class and decide the format
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy ");
```

//get current date time with Date()
Date date = new Date();

```
// Now format the date
String date1= dateFormat.format(date);

// Print the Date
System.out.println(date1);

collection_title.sendKeys("date1");
```

Answer (score 3):

In `collection_title.sendKeys("date1");` you are not using your variable date1, you are using the String "date1" - there should be no quotes around date1.

It should work like this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
collection_title.sendKeys(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to use LocalDateTime.now() or  Calender.getInstance() instead of new Date(), because the Date API methods are flawed and deprecated.